# How to export a result from Javascript to a csv file?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate a person's typing speed and then store it in an csv file. I can calculate the speed using a JavaScript program, but I do not know how to export the speeds to a csv file. I tried using Papaunparse, but that did not work. It's a server side csv file, called stats.

The speed variable is called spd. 
Below is a snippet of the code that calculates the speed and displays it to the user.

```
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    dayTwo = new Date();
    endType = dayTwo.getTime();
    totalTime = ((endType - startType) / 1000)
    spd = Math.round((word/totalTime) * 60)
    given = document.theForm.given.value.split(" ")
    typed = document.theForm.typed.value.split(" ")
    correct = 0
    len = 0 
    if(typed.length > given.length){
        len = typed.length
    }
    else{
        len = given.length
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(typed[i] === given[i]){
            correct += 1
        }
    }
    alert("\nYou got " + correct + "/" + given.length + "correct. \nYou typed a " + given.length + " word sentence in " 
    + totalTime + " seconds, a speed of about " + spd + " words per minute!" );
```

If someone could tell me how to export this speed to a csv file, it would be wonderful! Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community - The code you posted is not even related to what the issue is (create and download a CSV file) - the code you posted should be related to the use of 'Papaunparse' which did not work - tell us what you did and where it did not work and maybe we can be of help

Comment: Where is the CSV file? client/server

Comment: As another option, try taking a look at the HTML File System API (I will not provide a link for fear of further punishment from the SO elite). You would be able to write your CSV to a local file. This may not be what you need, but I feel that more information is better than less.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use `data:` URIs you can store your data on an [`<a>` element with a `[download]` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download).

```
<a href="data:text/csv,[your CSV data here]" download="filename.csv">Download</a>
```

If you're *not* able to use `data:` URIs or the `[download]` attribute, you'll need to host the data somewhere to be downloaded. This can be done in numerous ways. You could submit the data to a server and prompt the user with a link to download it, or you could render the CSV data on the page in a way the user could copy-paste, such as in a table, or maybe just as a `<textarea>` of data:

```
<textarea readonly>[your CSV data here]</textarea>
```

Comment: If I could downvote you, I would. Don't see how this is any more of an "answer" than mine was.

Comment: @chrisd1100, anyone looking at this answer should be able to use the code provided without needing to read either of the links I posted. On the other hand, your answer provides no information if the link were to no longer work.

Comment: keep in mind that the `download` attribute is not widely supported in IE or Safari (http://caniuse.com/#search=download) - if you need cross-browser support, you might need to use a server-side technology (such as PHP) to generate the file and provide it back to the browser

Comment: @ochi, absolutely, and there's less support for `data:` URIs as well.